# How to restore connection to WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, connection

I am using WPF as a client and WCF as a server.

Sometimes the machine that hosts the WCF loses internet connection for some minutes.

If the client request something to WCF while it's down, there is an exception, and I don't know how to try to restore connection. Even when the WCF server is up, once the client loses connection, it can't restore unless I reboot the client application.

How do I try to restore the connection in WPF (client) side?

Comment: Just create a new connection the same way you created the old connection.

Comment: how? Simply by creating a new instance of the Service? :o

Comment: Yes new instance of service will create new communication link and thereby the faulded state will be gone

Comment: ha! It worked! I didn't really think about it. Thanks!

Comment: Consider marking an answer ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be due to a faulted state.
A faulted state usually occurs because the service has hit an error which wasn't properly caught and handled on the server, and thus the communication link between client and server is "faulted". You have to recreate a whole new communication link to restore the connection.

Create new instance of service, it will create a new communication link and thereby the faulted state will be gone.

Comment: yeah, the key point is "Create new instance of service".
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have longrunning connections open, it's a bad practice

Keep you connections short, and dont use using

http://coding.abel.nu/2012/02/using-and-disposing-of-wcf-clients/